# Javascript Arithmetic shift right

Tags: javascript, node.js, bit-shift

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) the js arithmetic shift right and left operators are `<<` and `>>` and while the left shift seems to be working correctly, the right shift seems to be doing a bitwise shift rather than a arithmetic one

```
> 2 >> 1
1
> 2 << 1
4
> 1 >> 1
0
> 1 << 1
2
```

how can i get an arithmetic shift?

Comment: What results did you expect from your right shifts?

Comment: These are the expected results for a bitwise shift, I would expect an arithmetic shift in the scope of int64 so for the first operation `1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` and in the second `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001` or the base ten representations of `1` and `1`

Comment: I'm not clear why you'd expect that. Why would 2 >> 1 be anything but 1? An arithmatic shift (in an integer, anyway) just propagates the sign bit instead of shifting in a 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what values you are expecting. An arithmetic bit shift is what JavaScript does, but you will never see it without using negative values.

For example:
`-1 >> 1 === -1`
or
`-20 >> 1 === -10`

If these were standard logical bit shifts instead, the result would be dependent on the bit depth of the values, and not meaningful in the context of JavaScript. For example, the difference between logical and arithmetic bit shift in 8-bit (to keep it simple):

-1 would be 1111 1111:

1111 1111 arithmethic shift right = 1111 1111 (still -1, the high bit is "sticky")

1111 1111 logical shift right = 0111 1111 (now 127)

Edit: In JS, if you want to use a logical shift right, you can use >>> instead of >>. It works on 32-bit integers when you do. So:
`-1 >>> 1 === 2147483647`

Comment: Is there a way I can make sure the operations are being done in the `Uint8` type rather than a `int64` as the `number` class is? Also your description of the logical shift exactly matches my result of `1 >> 1 == 0` whereas no matter what typing would be `1` if it was an arithmetic shift. It would be much easier to see if it is working as intended if I was able to do all these operations in the `Uint8` class which I don't know how to call as it doesn't have one and the individual indexes of `Uint8Array` get converted to `int64`

Comment: Also if this was in fact an arithmetic shift `256 << 63` would return `128` even though it returns `0` whereas `256 << 64` returns `256`

Comment: It sounds like you are confusing a bit shift with a bit rotate. A bit shift left moves in 0s at the bottom each shift and that's it. A bit rotate left takes the bits shifted off the top and shifts them onto the bottom.

Comment: @Nationalism The arithmetic shift right only preserves the most significant bit (the sign). That means `1 >> 1 == 0`, as the MSB is `0` and the `1` (LSB) gets truncated in the shift.

Comment: Ah I see, I guess I was confusing the arithmetic shift with bit shift. Is there a bit shift operator in js? Thank you for your help

Comment: @Nationalism I think you're over-thinking the difference. In any case, there's an unsigned right-shift operator, `>>>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#bitwise_shift_operators

Comment: There isn't a built-in method for rotation unless someone knows one from a new standard I'm not familiar with. However, you can emulate it with 32-bit values:
Rotate Left: `(a << b) | (a >>> (32 - b))`
Rotate Right: `(a >>> b) | (a << (32 - b))`

Comment: @Nationalism It still sounds like you're conflating "bit shift" with "rotation". Bit shifts shift bits; that is all--rotation is a different thing.

Comment: @Nationalism Re: why `256 << 64 == 256` since the shift operators treat their values as 32-bit ints, meaning a shift of > 31 would mod over, it's likely it's being modulo-d be 0-31, same reason `256 << 32` is also `256`.